# Selenium IDE - waitForTextPresent

Tags: crash, selenium-ide, freeze

I have a problem with Selenium IDE's command - `waitForTextPresent`.

```
<tr>
<td>waitForTextPresent</td>
<td>*saved successfully</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

I had a couple of tests which are using this command. All tests worked fine, but now, during executing this command web application freeze, after while Firefox crashed, whole Firefox freezed and i received from Selenium IDE timeout exception after a while. So my question is, why is it happening?
I didn't change tests or selenium settings.

One time I received error:
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
Script: `chrome://selenium-ide/content/…nium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js:679`

Windows 7
Firefox 38.0.5
Selenium IDE: 2.8.0
I am using couple of add-ons related to Selenium (e.g.: Sel Block).

Answer (score 3):

`waitForTextPresent` is a deprecated command, try using just `waitForText` with a CSS locator as the target, and the '*saved successfully' bit as the value.

Comment: Hi Jsmith2800, thanks for your advice, it works perfect :) thank you

Comment: MAdeja if this answer worked for you please select it as the correct answer. Although now there may be better answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

You can use XPath for detecting the contained text as well For example:

```
waitForElementPresent | //*[@id="objectid" and contains(text(),"Text You Want")]
```

**Older solution with `waitForText`**:

You have to use WaitFortext

```
waitForText | Locator | Textpattern
```

for example

```
waitForText | //* | *saved successfully
```

asterisk can be used on beginning, middle or end of the text pattern

Comment: waitForTextPresent is deprecated but still available in older versions of the IDE. I would tweak your locator to be //body instead of //* but in either case, that's an ugly hack to get old functionality and you should provide as specific an locator as possible.

Comment: you can replace * in locator for whatever tag or full xpath as you want, but you did not specify the HTML at all. Asterisk (*) could be good if your application is in development and once it is <div> and in next version it is a <span> .. but the id or class persist.

Comment: I'd worry about performance of a low quality xpath like *. just my advice.

Comment: @DMart: It depends, if you app is under development, it is allright as your TCase is more flexible and you spend less time on TC maintenance. If your app is stable enough, you can be more specific. As we do not know anything about P. Madeia app and its html code, it is better to stay flexible.